# Initial segments of trees

Tags: notation, set-theory, self-learning, descriptive-set-theory

I am fairly sure this question will look quite trivial, but I have some trouble getting the reason behind the use of the symbole $\subset$ when we deal with sequences and initial segments of sequences. Indeed, to me this looks kind of – if not improper – at least potentially misleading.

Just few preliminaries to agree on the topic and notation.

> W.l.o.g. let $A$ be a countable set. then $A^\mathbb{N}$ be the set of sequences on $A$, i.e. the set of functions that map $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$. Thus, given $\sigma, \tau \in A^\mathbb{N}$, we write $\sigma \subset \tau$ to indicate that $\sigma$ is an *initial segment* of $\tau$.

As it stands now, this looks to me not completely precise. Indeed, if we distinguish (and we do!) between $\subset$ and $\subseteq$, by writing $\sigma \subset \tau$, then $\sigma \in A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ and $\tau \in A^\mathbb{N}$. Thus, $\sigma$ looks like $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$, where $\tau$ looks like  $(a_1, a_2, \dots)$. But then $\sigma$ is not *really* a **subset** of $\tau$.

Anyway, beyond this fact, just to get a confirmation, Is actually the case that in general $\sigma$ is a subset of $\tau$ and I don't see it, or it is simply what I wrote before, i.e. $\sigma$ is an *initial segment* of $\tau$, and *by chance* we use to express that notion the same symbol that we use for the set inclusion?

Thank you for your feedback and for your time.

PS: As I wrote, this question can look trivial, but when somebody is self-taught as I am, those little things that are written nowhere are exactly the one that are problematic (another typical example is the fact that in math, definitions are written only by using *if*, and not the proper *if and only if*. It took me a while and some lecture notes found somewhere to get this convention)

Comment: In mathematics, "if and only if" implies that a statement is valid in both directions; it can also be denoted as "$\iff$". For example, "A sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent $\iff$ $(x_n)$ is Cauchy." Thus, if the sequence is convergent, *then* it is Cauchy, and if the sequence is Cauchy, *then* it is convergent. Definitions do not usually require this.

Comment: Even if your comment should need an edit, to answer – stressing that this is not related in any way with my actual question – I would like to point that when we get an _iff_ theorem such as $A \Leftrightarrow B$, roughly we have something that is telling us that we can substitute $B$ to $A$ whenever we need to prove something about $A$. Definitions are not different at all: they are like "something is a $*** \Leftrightarrow B$", and again you substitute *** with $B$ (actually it is stronger, $***$ **is** $B$).Thus they act like an _iff_, but they are written as _if_, and this is a convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the set-theoretic view that a sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ in $A$ is just a function $a : \{1,\ldots,n\}\to A$, and that a function is just a set of ordered pairs, then actually any initial segment of a sequence is a subset of that sequence, since the sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is equal to the set $$\{(1,a_1),\ldots,(n,a_n)\}$$whereas the infinite sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_n,a_{n+1},\ldots)$ is equal to the set $$\{(1,a_1),\ldots,(n,a_n),(n+1,a_{n+1}),\ldots\}$$

**Edit:** I should point out that there are subsets which are not initial segments (e.g. the subset $\{(2n,a_{2n}) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$), though every subset is a *subsequence* in a certain sense.  I think some set-theorists use an alternate notation to $\subseteq$ to indicate that a sequence is an initial segment, and not just a subsequence.